# How do I get JQuery event target's text value on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

On Windows, in every browser I tried, the below commands

```
console.log($(e.target).text());   // <--- this works
console.log($(e.target).siblings().text());                     
console.log($(e.target).siblings().children('.someclassname').text());

console.log($(e.target));   
console.log($(e.target).siblings());                        
console.log($(e.target).siblings().children('.someclassname'));
```

gave me the event target's proper inside text contents with text() method, or an object with viewable keys and values if used without.

On Android, however, using webview in Android Studio, the chromium console shows

`""` (empty string) when used with text() **except the first case, which shows text() contents correctly**  - even though those were not empty at all in Windows internet browsers - and
`[Object object]` (even those were proper objects) when used without text().

Indeed, any of my scripts that relied on parsing text() did not work on any Android browsers despite working fine on Windows ones.

How do I get the text() method to work on Android? Is there some workaround to get the element's text value that works on Android (preferably with JQuery, but I can accept other options)?

Comment: I've run scripts that used `.text()` in the Chrome browser on my Android phone and gotten normal results, i.e., the same results as on my desktop browser. There's no special trick to it. Can you maybe create a small demo at jsfiddle.net which we could run on our phones to check if we get the same result as you?

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you strictly need to do it using jquery, but you can also do that (example of the input search on stackoverflow)

```
console.log(document.querySelector('[name="q"]').value);
```

Where "q" is the name of the input field :)

Hope it will help

Comment: I don't think the OP's elements are inputs, so they wouldn't have a `.value` property. (If they *were* inputs then in the jQuery code they should be using `.val()` rather than `.text()`.)